# Unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'

Tags: python

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'

What do I need to change to fix this?

```
string_1 = "Sean";
string_2 = "beginner programmer";

print("Hi my name is %s, I\'m a %s.") % (string_1,string_2);
```

Comment: Also you don't need `;` at the end of every line in Python. Python use indented syntax

Answer (score 12):

`print` returns `None`, you must format the string *before* printing it

```
print("Hi my name is %s, I\'m a %s." % (string_1, string_2))
```